# Long text in scrollable textblock is cropped

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, textblock

I want place long text into a textblock i´m using:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto">
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">                 
   <Run Text=""/>
   <LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
   <Run Text=""/>
   <LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
   <Run Text=""/>
   <LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
   <Run Text=""/>
   <LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
 </TextBlock>                
</scrollviewer>
```

When text is really long it is cropped, what can i do to see all text

sorry, but my english is not good

Answer (score 2):

> The reason for this behavior is that any element that must be displayed beyond the area which is larger than 2048x2048 pixels would be clipped by the platform.

Look at this [solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx).